# Ruby Programming Techniques: simple yet not so simple object manipulation

Tags: ruby, math

I want to create an object, let's say a Pie.

```
class Pie 
  def initialize(name, flavor) 
    @name = name 
    @flavor = flavor 
  end 
end
```

But a Pie can be divided in 8 pieces, a half or just a whole Pie. For the sake of argument, I would like to know how I could give each Pie object a price per 1/8, 1/4 or per whole. I could do this by doing:

```
class Pie 
  def initialize(name, flavor, price_all, price_half, price_piece) 
    @name = name 
    @flavor = flavor 
    @price_all = price_all
    @price_half = price_half
    @price_piece = price_piece
  end 
end
```

But now, if I would create fifteen Pie objects, and I would take out randomly some pieces somewhere by using a method such as

```
getPieceOfPie(pie_name)
```

How would I be able to generate the value of all the available pies that are whole and the remaining pieces? Eventually using a method such as:

```
   myCurrentInventoryHas(pie_name)
   # output: 2 whole strawberry pies and 7 pieces.
```

I know, I am a Ruby nuby. Thank you for your answers, comments and help!

Comment: +1 for that term - Ruby Nuby :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll definitely want separate `Pie` and `PiePiece` classes

```
class Pie
  attr_accessor :pieces
  def initialize
    self.pieces = []
  end

  def add_piece(flavor)
    raise "Pie cannot have more than 8 pieces!" if pieces.count == 8
    self.pieces << PiePiece.new(flavor)
  end

  # a ruby genius could probably write this better... chime in if you can help
  def inventory
    Hash[pieces.group_by(&:flavor).map{|f,p| [f, p.size]}]
  end

end

class PiePiece
  attr_accessor :flavor
  def initialize(flavor)
    self.flavor = flavor
  end
end
```

### sample code

```
p = Pie.new
p.add_piece(:strawberry)
p.add_piece(:strawberry)
p.add_piece(:apple)
p.add_piece(:cherry)
p.add_piece(:cherry)
p.add_piece(:cherry)

p.inventory.each_pair do |flavor, count|
  puts "Pieces of #{flavor}: #{count}"
end

# output
# Pieces of strawberry: 2
# Pieces of apple: 1
# Pieces of cherry: 3
```

Comment: Sweet, I like this answer. Indeed it's the inventory counting I'm struggling with. Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: @Shyam, I updated the post to show a *possible* way to do the inventory counting. Someone who has a better mastery of `Array` and `Hash` methods would probably be able to write it better though :)

Comment: Excellent. No need for a genius, you already did a great job. Thanks!

Comment: @Shyam, @mckeed helped out. I updated the `Pie#inventory` method to showcase his genius.

Answer (score 3):

Could you create a PieSlice object, and each Pie would have an array of PieSlices?

Answer (score 1):

The Pie class could have a counter to indicate what fraction of it remains. The `getPieceOfPie` method would modify this counter. The `myCurrentInventoryHas` method could then look at each Pie and see how much of that Pie there is be examining the counter.

Answer (score 0):

A piece of pie is not a pie.

(talking in oo terms, an object should have a clear responsibility, making an object a pie AND a slice may not be a clear responsibility assignment).

Comment: I do agree with you. And one of the reasons of asking this question is to figure out the solution using OO and elegancy.

Comment: I think that if you have a Pie with an array of slices, there is no "violation" of the OO principles.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with your pie and pieces. If you can assume that each piece is independent (you don't need to know if a pie is cut or not) you probably need only a PieInventory and a PiePiece. The inventory can grow and shrink as you call push_pieces(n) and pull_pieces(n).

Comment: But what if I would want to know when a pie is cut? It is the whole idea of the question! I know, its an awkward one, but thats why its bugging me :)

Comment: I would just suppose that you have n/8 pies and n%8 cut pieces. Why would you cut more than one pie at a time?