# Calculate sum of objects for each unique object property in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

I was helping with an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625257/ruby-programming-techniques-simple-yet-not-so-simple-object-manipulation) and it sparked a question of my own.

1. `Pie` is an object that has a `pieces` array made of of `PiePiece` objects.
2. Each `PiePiece` has a `flavor` attribute

How do I create a hash that looks like this:

```
# flavor => number of pieces
{
  :cherry => 3
  :apple => 1
  :strawberry => 2
}
```

This works, but I think it could be improved

```
def inventory
  hash = {}
  pieces.each do |p|
    hash[p.flavor] ||= 0
    hash[p.flavor] += 1
  end
  hash
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def inventory
  Hash[pieces.group_by(&:flavor).map{|f,p| [f, p.size]}]
end
```

Comment: Nice. Never even knew group_by existed.

Comment: It's new to Ruby 1.8.7. Just `require "backports"` if using 1.8.6. BTW, `Hash[key_value_pairs]` is also new to 1.8.7